# Subsequence of measures which have a weak limit

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I saw an example of a sequence of measures for which no subsequence can have a weak limit, but don't think it is correct.

Let $(\delta_{x_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of Dirac measures and let $ (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \infty$

Note that it was not further specified what the probability space of the dirac measures really is, so lets assume $ (\overline{\mathbb{R}}, \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}) )$ which is the extended Borelspace. Let $f$ be a real bounded continuous function, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}f\,\mathrm{d}\delta_{x_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(\infty)= \int_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}f\,\mathrm{d}\delta_{\infty}$$

i.e. it converges weakly. What is the problem, why should it not work?

Comment: The underlying space must not be compact for this counterexample to work. If you consider $\mathbb R^n$, for example, then it makes no sense to write $f(\infty)$.

Comment: There’s no reason for $\lim_n f(x_n)$ to exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying space is intended to be $\mathbb R$, not its compactification. Thus, bounded and continuous functions may fail to have a limit at infinity. For example, assuming that $x_n=(n+\tfrac12)\pi$ (thank you Nate), consider the bounded and continuous function 
$$
f(x)=\sin(x).$$
If the sequence $\delta_{x_n}$ had a limit, say $\mu$, then it should be possible to integrate all bounded and continuous functions against it; however,
$$
\int f(x)\, d\mu=\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n). $$
Now, this last limit does not exists for any subsequence of $x_n$. Thus $\mu$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the limit does exist for some sequences $x_n$.  So we should have a particular sequence in mind, e.g. $x_n = (n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi$.

Comment: You are totally right, Nate, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: The underlying space can be any Borel-space in my definition. Why is the compactification excluded? But your example works in the compactification, too.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: If $X$ is a compact space, then any sequence $x_n\in X$ has a convergent subsequence. Correspondingly, $\delta_{x_n} $ has a convergent subsequence. Besides, what would "$x_n\to \infty$" mean, on a compact space?